# yeoman grunt-connect-proxy not working

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

When i run my grunt server with task "`grunt server:dist --force`" i get

```
 Running "configureProxies" task
 Proxy created for: /securedGateway to 104.92.356.167:80
```

And when i load my page i get 404 on all rest calls. I have done proxy using nginx server it works fine but using grunt for proxy task doesn't seems to be working for me.

here is my grunt file: -

```
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);
    var proxySnippet = require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest;
    // configurable paths
    var yeomanConfig={

        app: 'app',
            dist: 'dist'
//      dist: '/c/eclipse-jee/eclipse/workspace/bo/WebContent/mybo'
    }
  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: yeomanConfig,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['bowerInstall']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      less: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/assets/less/*.less'],
        tasks: ['less:server']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/assets/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
    proxies: [
        {
            context: "/securedGateway",
            host: '104.238.94.167',
            port: 80,
            https: false,
            changeOrigin: true,
            headers: {
                'host': '104.238.94.167'
            },

    }],
      // courtesy of Phubase Tiewthanom
      livereload: {
    options: {
        open:true,
        base: [
            '.tmp',
             yeomanConfig.app
        ],
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [proxySnippet,
            connect.static(require('path').resolve('app')),
            connect.static(require('path').resolve('.tmp')),
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
             connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect.static(require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app')
        ];
      }
    }
  },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            'test',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
      ],
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/assets/css/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/assets/css/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    bowerInstall: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/',
        exclude: ['requirejs',
                  'mocha',
                  'jquery.vmap.europe.js',
                  'jquery.vmap.usa.js',
                  'Chart.min.js',
                  'raphael',
                  'morris',
//                  'jquery.inputmask',inputmask
                  'jquery.validate.js',
                  'jquery.stepy.js'
                  ]
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/css/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              //js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              js: ['concat'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/assets/css/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    cssmin: {
      options: {
        // root: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
        relativeTo: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
        processImport: true,
        noAdvanced: true
      }
    },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // ngmin tries to make the code safe for minification automatically by
    // using the Angular long form for dependency injection. It doesn't work on
    // things like resolve or inject so those have to be done manually.
    ngmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            // 'views/*/{,*/}*.html',
            'views/**',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'fonts/*',
            'assets/**',
            'bower_components/**',
            'styles/main.css',
//            'bower_components/jquery.inputmask/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js',
            'bower_components/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js',
            'bower_components/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.europe.js',
            'bower_components/jqvmap/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.usa.js',
            'bower_components/stepy/lib/jquery.stepy.js',
            'bower_components/Chart.js/Chart.min.js',
            'bower_components/raphael/raphael.js',
            'bower_components/morris.js/morris.js'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }]
      },
      tomcatServer: {
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        src: '**/*',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.tomcatServer %>',
        expand: true
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/assets/css',
        dest: '.tmp/assets/css',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },
    ngtemplates:  {
      app: {
        src:      'app/views/templates/**.html',
        dest:     'app/scripts/templates/templates.js',
        options:  {
          url:    function(url) { return url.replace('app/views/', ''); },
          bootstrap: function(module, script) {
            return "angular.module('theme.templates', []).run(['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {\n"+script+"}])";
          }
        },
      }
    },

    less: {
      server: {
        options: {
          // strictMath: true,
          dumpLineNumbers: true,
          sourceMap: true,
          sourceMapRootpath: "",
          outputSourceFiles: true
        },
        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            cwd: "<%= yeoman.app %>/assets/less",
            src: "styles.less",
            dest: ".tmp/assets/css",
            ext: ".css"
          }
        ]
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          cleancss: true,
          report: 'min'
        },
        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            cwd: "<%= yeoman.app %>/assets/less",
            src: "styles.less",
            dest: ".tmp/assets/css",
            ext: ".css"
          }
        ]
      }
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //         '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    },
    processhtml: {
      options: {
        commentMarker: 'prochtml',
        process: true
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html': ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html']
        }
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      options: {
        mangle: false
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'bowerInstall',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',

      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'bowerInstall',
    'ngtemplates',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'less:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
      'configureProxies',
    // 'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    // 'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    //'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin',
    'processhtml:dist',
    // 'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    // 'newer:jshint',
    // 'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Comment: Please help me out , I am stucked :(

Comment: have you got any solutions. I am also stucked :(